# How to test Angular directive with TemplateUrl?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I understand that this question has been asked several times. But I really don't get it. I can't figure out how to test directive using karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor.

I have the following:

```
var admin = angular.module('admin', []);

admin.controller('theMenu', ['$scope', function() {
     $scope.items = [{ link: 'a', desc: 'b' }];
}]).directive('backend', function() {
     return {
           scope: { menuItems: '=' },
           templateUrl: 'template/menuBar.html'
     }
});
```

I then have the following test:

```
describe('Test', function() {

     var $rootScope;
     var $controller;
     var $compile;
     var $templateCache;

    beforeEach(function() {
            module('admin');
    });

    beforeEach(function() {
            module('menuBar.html');
    });

    beforeEach(function() {
            inject(function(_$templateCache_, _$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$compile_) {
                    $controller = _$controller_;
                    $templateCache = _$templateCache_;
                    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
                    $compile = _$compile_;
            });
    });

    it('', function() {
            var $scope = {};
            var controller = $controller('theMenu', { $scope: $scope });
            var element = $compile($templateCache.get('menuBar.html'))($rootScope);
            $rootScope.$digest();
            console.log(element.html());  //console output nothing. This is my problem;
            expect(element.html()).toEqual('...');
    });
});
```

My template is:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="r in menuItems">{{ r.link }}{{ r.desc }}</li>
</ul>
```

The code for module menuBar.html is the following. This is generated by karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor:

```
angular.module('menuBar.html', []).run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('menuBar.html', '<ul><li ng-repeat="r in menuItems">{{ r.link }}{{ r.desc }}</li></ul>');
}]);
```

I believe there must be mistakes in my code. I don't know why the console output is empty. I believe the console output would be

```
<ul><li>ab</li></ul>
```

Thanks in advance for pointing out my mistakes.

Comment: What is this `menuBar.html` module? Also, what is your question?

Comment: I have edited the question. I don't know why the console.log call output nothing.